# Eliminar hash de una aplicación angular

Tags: angular

Hola amigos buenas noches, de casualidad alguien sabe como remover el # de la url de angular 10?

URL que muestra:

```
https://localhost:4200/homePage#/
```

URL esperada:

```
https://localhost:4200/homePage
```

Answer (score 1):

El uso de *hash*, almohadilla o gato (el carácter `#`) ha de estar definido en las rutas. Comprueba si tienes algo como

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
```

en el módulo de tu aplicación.